# tomcat maven plugin

Tags: apache, java-ee, maven, tomcat

Не могу запустить корректно maven tomcat plugin плагин.
Мб я что-то делаю не парвильно, но не понимаю что. OS Debian 8.4(мб там в переменные что-то надо ещё добавлять...?)

pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.2</version>
     <configuration>
          <server>myTomcat</server>
          <url>http://localhost:8080/</url>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

settings.xml:

```
<server>
    <id>myTomcat</id>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>admin</password>
</server>
```

tomcat-users.xml:

```
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="tomcat,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
```

когда делаю mvn tomcat7:run , ошибка:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) on project erp_trtaffic_system: Could not start Tomcat: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]: A child container failed during start -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException



при mvn tomcat7:deploy (redeploy)

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:redeploy (default-cli) on project erp_trtaffic_system: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection reset -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:redeploy (default-cli) on project erp_trtaffic_system: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:68)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:181)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager$RequestEntityImplementation.writeTo(TomcatManager.java:880)
        at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
        at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:117)
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:265)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:203)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:682)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:742)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:705)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:388)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:82)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:132)
        ... 23 more

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] 

http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
root@debian:~/projects/erp_traffic$
```

Comment: Это мертвый плагин. Используйте [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html).

Comment: У меня получилось его завести, но да, уже поставил плагин с jetty